# Take difference of elements in a list of pairs in Scala

Tags: scala

There is a list lets say:[1,2,3].I am trying to find the difference of every 2 consecutive numbers and then add them.

eg : the above list would give:(2-1)+(3-2)=2.I am looking to find a solution which doesn't use loops.
Code:

```
val e = List((0,true), (2,true), (7,true))
val w = e.foldLeft(e(0)){ (z1,z2) => z2._1 - z1._1  }
```

Can anyone please provide a suggestion why the above code is wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `z2._1 - z1._1` has a type of `Int`, but you should return `(Int, Boolean)` in your function. As an example: `(z2._1 - z1._1, true)` or `(z2._1 - z1._1, false)` or `(z2._1 - z1._1, z1._2)`, or `(z2._1 - z1._1, z2._2)` etc.

Comment: your requirement simplifies to the difference between the first and last elements in your list, i.e. `l.last - l.head`

Comment: [Telescope sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to convert the list of tuples to a list of integers using **map**

```
def sum(list: List[Int]) = {
  list.sliding(2).toList.map {
    case List(v1, v2) => v2 - v1
  }.sum
}

val e1 = List(0 -> true, 2 -> true, 7 -> true)

val res1 = sum(e1.map(_._1))

val e2 = List(1 -> true, 2 -> true, 3 -> true)

val res2 = sum(e2.map(_._1))
```

produces:

```
res1: Int = 7
res2: Int = 2
```

Comment: `toList` not needed. Comment from Joel Berkeley is correct: can be simplified to `list.last - list.head`.

Comment: Oh, I agree. Please disregard then

Answer (score 1):

```
 e.unzip._1.sliding(2).map{case List(i, j) => j-i}.sum
```

### Tests in SCALA REPL:

```
scala> val e1 = List(0 -> true, 2 -> true, 7 -> true)
e1: List[(Int, Boolean)] = List((0,true), (2,true), (7,true))

scala> e1.unzip._1.sliding(2).map{case List(i, j) => j-i}.sum
res190: Int = 7

scala> val e2 = List(1 -> true, 2 -> true, 3 -> true)
e2: List[(Int, Boolean)] = List((1,true), (2,true), (3,true))

scala> e2.unzip._1.sliding(2).map{case List(i, j) => j-i}.sum
res191: Int = 2

scala>
```

Comment: The first one doesn't seem like it would work in general, since `e1.toMap.keySet.toList` doesn't necessarily preserve the order of elements.

Comment: Agreed...just removed it. It may not work for general cases. thanks Brian for the correction

Comment: `.toList` not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could get it with 
e.foldLeft(e(0)){ (z1,z2) => (z2._1 - z1._1 , z2._2)}._1

The reason is, you are trying to change the element type, which is not allowing.

Comment: thanks for the answer ,just that your code is outputting 5 not 7.